# Space of Homomorphisms Between Two Group Modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups, modules, representation-theory

I am currently self-studying the representation theory of the symmetric group by following the book *The Symmetric Group* by Bruce E. Sagan. All groups here are finite and the base field is $\mathbb{C}$. I'm having trouble seeing how he arrives at the following proposition:

> Proposition 1.7.10. Let $V$ and $W$ be $G$-modules with $V$ irreducible. Then dim Hom$(V,W)$ is the multiplicity of $V$ in $W$.

For context, in the chapter before this Sagan stated a weaker result that the dimension of Hom$(V,W) = 0$ if and only if there is no submodule of $W$ isomorphic to $V$. This was a corollary of Schur's Lemma.

I don't see how he comes up with this stronger result though. He states it immediately after classifying the endomorphism algebra corresponding to a $G$-module and he says 'similar methods can be used' to obtain Proposition 1.7.10, which implies that they are related but I don't see how.

Can anyone offer some insight into this? At the moment I feel like this proposition just follows from the uniqueness of the decomposition of $W$ into irreducibles via Maschke's Theorem (can someone confirm if I'm correct in thinking this?). But Sagan doesn't prove the uniqueness of the decomposition and seems to be going a different route which I don't follow.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write $W=\bigoplus_{j=1}^m W_j$ with the $W_j$ irreducible. Then
$$\text{Hom}(V,W)=\text{Hom}\left(V,\bigoplus_{j=1}^m W_j\right)
\cong\bigoplus_{j=1}^m \text{Hom}(V,W_j)$$
and so
$$\dim\text{Hom}(V,W)=\sum_{j=1}^m \dim\text{Hom}(V,W_j).$$
By Schur's lemma, $\dim\text{Hom}(V,W_j)=1$ or $0$ according
to whether or not $W_j$ is isomorphic to $V$ or not. Therefore
$\dim\text{Hom}(V,W)$ is the number of $W_j$ which are isomorphic to $V$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I follow everything except I hadn't seen that isomorphism between the Hom spaces. Do you have a reference for that somewhere?

Comment: This is a general property of direct sums of modules: for $R$-modules, $M$, $N_1$ and $N_2$, $$\text{Hom}_R(M,N_1\oplus N_2)\cong\text{Hom}_R(M,N_1)\oplus\text{Hom}_R(M,N_2).$$ Essentially a homomorphism from $M$ to $N_1\oplus N_2$ consists of a homomorphism from $M$ to $N_1$ and a homomorphism from $M$ to $N_2$.

Comment: I see. I also think this thread discusses the isomorphism: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/497582/homomorphism-from-direct-sum-of-vector-spaces